# Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

l saw this problem many questions but l couldn't find the solution for myself. When l use WAMPSERVER it works with this way, but when l try hosting(free hosting) it gives this error. l am not very experienced so l am open to all answers. Thank you.

> (Error: Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory)

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$dbname     = 'pro1';
$username   = 'user1'; 
$password   = 'barbar55'; 
$port       = '3306'; 
try { 
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;port=$port", $username, $password); 
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
  echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) { 
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage(); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: I don't know about free hosting services but I do know that most MySQL servers are NOT in the localhost domain.  Check your provider for the actual MySQL path.

Answer (score 2):

Try replace `localhost` (socket connection)  by IP address `127.0.0.1` (TCP connection)

Comment: I did that. It gave an error as well. "Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused". Can lp adress change depends where you live?I live in Turkey btw.

Comment: edit: "infinityfree" free hosting l use, l think they don't let it beacuse it's free version. l am not sure but this may be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I find out the problem. Aperently hosting service has a PANEL that l MUST use(silly me). It's my first time doing this so thanks for the answers.